# XSL-FO table content to continue on next page without pushing down sibling content

Tags: .net, xslt, xsl-fo, ecrion

I am testing out XSL-FO with a FO-processor for .NET. The FOP i am using is Ecrion.

If i have a table being populated by dynamic data from a data source on page 1 and beneath that table there is another static table on the same page. I want the dynamic table to continue on the next page if it stretches down to the static one (because of the number of items in the list that populates the table).

The behavior that I'm getting is that the dynamic table pushes down the static one resulting it to be rendered after the last row on the next page.

My question is: How can I make the layout behave so that the dynamic table (placed first on page 1, right before the static table) continues on the next page without pushing the static table down with it?

I have made som mocks that describes what I want and what I actually get:

**This picture describes the behavior that I demand:**
[image: What i want]

**And this picture describes the behavior that i get:**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answer is OK, but a footer will only work if you have a different page template for this page versus others. It is OK if you have a region-after for "first" and this only occurs on "first".

A better solution for this is to place the table you wish at the bottom in a footnote.

Comment: That just made the static table to be pushed to the bottom of the second page whenever the content of the dynamic one reached the end of the first page. Am I missing some attribute or something?

Comment: you must put the footnote on the page on which you want it. perhaps at the beginning of the dynamic table.

Answer (score 1):

You could place the table with static data in the footer region instead of the body text region. Create a footer that contains the static data, and create a page-sequence-master which uses this footer. That way you can switch between normal pages (without the table in the footer) and special pages (with table in the footer).